# NumPy stack different dimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a feature matrix of dimension (60000, 28, 28) and a target array of dimension (60000,). Is there a way to concatenate or stack them in order to make it a single matrix?

Comment: What do you want the output shape to be?

Comment: Probably (60000,28,28,1).

Comment: Let's not guess.  What you plan on doing with this array will determine what the shape should be.   I'd suggest keeping them separate, util you have a clear idea of what a combination will look like and how it will be used.

Comment: Yes, I want the output shape to be (60000, 28, 28,1)

Comment: In that case reshape the feature matrix and throw away the target.

Comment: I don't think you understand array dimensions.  A (N, x, x, 1) array can't hold anything more than a (N, x, x) one.  The added dimension doesn't increase its size.  There isn't a way of adding a (N,) array to this, and still produce a multidimensional array.  The dimensions don't add up.

Comment: You can use `.reshape` to change the dimensions of the array as you like... as long as the total size remains constant (i.e. you have the same number of elements). If you want to change the total size of the array, first you need to think what you want to do with the missing / extra elements. Note the difference between "size" and "shape": also note that you don't need to create a "target" array, just reshape the original one.